# how to have different settings for content in mobile/desktop view?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have installed Custom Search Engine on my Website with the overlay layout. Thing is it shows full width in desktop view so I put the script between `<div class="reduce">...</div>` and added a custom CSS file to reduce the width of the bar. The CSS code is as below :

```
.reduce
{
width:35%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Google Custom Search Engine code :

```
<div class="reduce">
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '012035866174049355570:ld4iogvd2ok';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

It looks good on the desktop view but if viewed on mobile, the search bar is cluttered. So is there any way I can code it so that when the website is opened on a desktop, it'll run the above css and when it detects a mobile, the width is changed to 100%?

This is the [LINK](http://www.cyberfosters.com) to the website.

Comment: How did you install Custom Search Engine??? Show an example in fiddle or similar :)

Comment: I meant the Google Custom Search Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries or simply add a fixed max-width and width 100%

```
.reduce {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 555px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

With media queries you will have it like this. First the regular style for .reduce and then with media queries you will target all devices from 768px and less (tablets and mobile).

```
.reduce {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 35%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 768px){
    .reduce {            
        max-width: 100%;            
    }
}
```

:)

Comment: This is it! Works! I completely forgot about the max-width property!

Comment: One question though, how did you translate 35% to 555px? Won't the search bar look small in very high resolution screens?

Comment: 35% in my browser was 555px :) But you can add how much you want. Although if you worry about how the search bar will look in hight resolution, than you can make it with media queries :) Or you can make it as wide as the page content div so they are more compact together :)

Comment: Can you please help me with that? I'm not that accustomed to using media queries. For now I've implemented the above code but I'd really like to have the width set in %

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query:

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .reduce {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 701px) {
  .reduce {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reduce" style="background:red; height:50px;"></div>
```

Change `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` to whatever width you think your website looks cramped at